# Is the poison from Stink Bugs dangerous?

Tags: entomology

I just went to kill what I thought was a moth on the wall, and instead it fell on the floor and it sounded like dropping a coffee bean (because of the hard shell)

I live in the UK and have never seen one of these things before, I thought maybe it was a variant of a woodlouse, so I just crushed it in some kitchen roll I had over my hand and saw a little stain on the paper, but I assumed it was just blood.

When I looked on the internet and discovered what it was, I smelled my hand and it stank (I'd literally washed my hands like a minute or two before killing this thing). Since I've touched my laptop keyboard and stuff, is that a problem? If I use my laptop and now eat something will it poison me or leave an awful taste in my mouth?

P.S. If this seems OTT I do have slight OCD when it comes to hygiene and bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there are no poisonous species ([see this website](http://animals.pawnation.com/stink-bugs-poisonous-7670.html)), and some species are even eaten ([website](http://www.scienceinafrica.com/old/index.php?q=2003/october/stinkbug.htm)). No worries.